# python udp server parse and send received data to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sockets, udp

i am working on some proof of concept study research project and have python udp socket server that listen received data.
Client send data NAME and FAMILY NAME on UDP to server.
I would like to receive that data on UDP socket server side and on receive send this data to mysql database with two fields f_name and l_name.

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "192.168.1.10"
UDP_PORT = 9000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
print "UDP SERVER STARTED!"

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print "MSG Received:", data
```

this example is taken from web and with this server i get data on console.
I would like to have it like below and of course code/concept can be changed. This might be solved with scapy sniffer but that would be dirty.
Conceptually i would like to have ti something like:
1. socekt server received data
2. parse data received and send this data to mysql

I started with this in mind but doesnt work

```
import socket
import MySQLdb

UDP_IP = "192.168.1.10"
UDP_PORT = 9000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
print "UDP SERVER STARTED!"

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print "received message:", data

def parse(data):
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","db_user","db_pass","directory_db")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    # Params to insert into DB
    f_nameObj = re.search(r'NAME: (.*?) .*', data, re.M|re.I)
    if f_name:
        f_name = f_nameObj.group(1)

    l_nameObj = re.search(r'SURNAME: (.*?) .*', data, re.M|re.I)
    if l_name:
        l_name = l_nameObj.group(1)

    # MySQL EXECUTION
    cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO dictionary (f_name, l_name) VALUES (%s, %s)""",(f_name,l_name))
    #
    db.commit()
```

With this kind of udp server i see no messages so seems function that parse data is not working with server.
Any help or guidance would be appreciated

Comment: What is your problem? Any exception?

Comment: i see no data if in def parse(data) function. If just start udp server i see on console data is coming but i would like to have it in function to send to db

Answer (score 0):

In your server when you receive `data` you don't call `parse` function.You just print the content of `data`. Add the line with the comment and see the result.

```
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print "received message:", data
    parse(data) # Call the Function
```